# android - R.string.[variable] in a For loop?

Tags: string, for-loop

I am trying to create a `R.string.[variable]` in a `for` loop to save me lots of lines of code.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

inside strings.xml, I have these

```
<string name="posA1">Position A 1</string>
<string name="posA2">Position A 2</string>
<string name="posA3">Position A 3</string>
...etc
```

main.java

```
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        ...
        string = R.string. + "posA" + j;
        ...
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about an array?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  
<string-array name="testArray">  
    <item>first</item>  
    <item>second</item>  
    <item>third</item>  
    <item>fourth</item>  
    <item>fifth</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

and then in your code:

```
String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length(); i++) {
    String string = myArray[i];
}
```